# How to use Autofac Dependency Injection in MassTransit IConsume

Tags: autofac, masstransit

I'm trying to use DI with my consumer class without success.

My consumer class:

```cs
public class TakeMeasureConsumer : IConsumer<TakeMeasure>
{

    private IUnitOfWorkAsync _uow;
    private IInstrumentOutputDomainService _instrumentOutputDomainService;


    public TakeMeasureConsumer(IUnitOfWorkAsync uow,
        IInstrumentOutputDomainService instrumentOutputDomainService)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _instrumentOutputDomainService = instrumentOutputDomainService;
    }


    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TakeMeasure> context)
    {

        var instrumentOutput = Mapper.Map<InstrumentOutput>(context.Message);

        _instrumentOutputDomainService.Insert(instrumentOutput);
        await _uow.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
}
```

When I want to register the bus factory the consumer must have a parameterless constructor.

```cs
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{

    builder.Register(context =>
        Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "intrument_take_measure", e =>
            {
                // Must be a non abastract type with a parameterless constructor....
                e.Consumer<TakeMeasureConsumer>();

            });  

        }))
    .SingleInstance()
    .As<IBusControl>()
    .As<IBus>();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I really don't know how to register my consumer...

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Integrating with Autofac is easy, there are extension methods in the `MassTransit.Autofac` package that help out.

First, there is an `AutofacConsumerFactory` that will resolve your consumers from the container. You can add this to the container, or you can register it yourself using:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(AutofacConsumerFactory<>))
    .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("name", "message"))
    .As(typeof(IConsumerFactory<>));
```

Then, in the builder statement for the bus and receive endpoint:

```
e.Consumer(() => context.Resolve<IConsumerFactory<TakeMeasureConsumer>());
```

This will then resolve your consumers from the container.

**Update:**

For newer versions of MassTransit add receive endpoints like this:

```
e.Consumer<TakeMeasureConsumer>(context);
```

Comment: Hi Chris,  this is now working for me.  The masstransit.Autofac  package makes it really easy and masstransit is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Chris Patterson, code in your answer seems is not working. context.Resolve<AutofacConsumerFactory> - but you registered IConsumerFactory. When i changed that, i've got resolution issue: Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MassTransit.AutofacIntegration.AutofacConsumerFactory`1

Comment: Try like this: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Host/ContainerBuilderExtensions.cs#L28

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry to bother you again but I got this error now in the builder statement for the receive endpoint: The type 'AutofacConsumerFactory<CanAuto.Instrument.Handlers.TakeMeasureConsumer>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TConsumer' in the generic type or method 'ConsumerExtensions.Consumer<TConsumer>(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator, Func<TConsumer>, Action<IConsumerConfigurator<TConsumer>>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MassTransit.AutofacIntegration.AutofacConsumerFactory<CanAuto.Instrument.Handlers.TakeMeasureConsumer>' to 'MassTransit.IConsumer'.

Comment: I edited the above to make sure it's right, that works and verified.

Comment: Thanks Chris,  I was just missing to set up the lifetime scope for AutofacConsumerFactory, adding InstancePerLifetimeScope() has solved my issue,  thanks again!

Comment: Hi. I am using MassTransit 3.5.7 and I am trying to add multiple receive endpoints. Does it work with e.LoadFrom(context);? Or should I specify the consumer for each receive endpoint? I am trying to specify the consumers as you suggested, using IConsumerFactory, but I get the an error (posted in the following comment). Could you point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: The type 'MassTransit.IConsumerFactory<OrderPlacedConsumer>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TConsumer' in the generic type or method 'ConsumerExtensions.Consumer<TConsumer>(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator, Func<TConsumer>, Action<IConsumerConfigurator<TConsumer>>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MassTransit.IConsumerFactory<OrderPlacedConsumer>' to 'MassTransit.IConsumer'.

Comment: I succeded like this: e.Consumer<OrderPlacedConsumer>(context); Can I update your answer with this line?

Comment: I would update the answer with the latest updates from the documentation: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/autofac.html